# (Titling) Why do figures and math squish my title, author and date?

Tags: titling

It seems that when trying to add math or figures to a doc, all 3 get squished. It makes documents look unconsistent, and I'm wondering if there is a fix for this.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage[showframe, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}[Ligatures=TeX]
    \setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\setlength{\droptitle}{-2cm}

\renewcommand{\maketitlehookb}{\vspace{-1cm}} 

\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}{\vspace{-.5cm}} 

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

% }

\title{Title of Document}
\author{Author Name Generic}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle



\end{document}
```

Code with math for comparison

```
% {
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage[showframe, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}[Ligatures=TeX]
    \setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\setlength{\droptitle}{-2cm}

\renewcommand{\maketitlehookb}{\vspace{-1cm}} 

\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}{\vspace{-.5cm}} 

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

% }

\title{Title of Document}
\author{Author Name Generic}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

      Identities \newline

            The Sum and Difference Identities

            \begin{gather}
                \cos(\alpha - \beta) = \cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) + \sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\\
                \cos(\alpha + \beta) = \cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) - \sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\\
                \sin(\alpha + \beta) = \sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) + \cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\\
                \sin(\alpha - \beta) = \sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) - \cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)
            \end{gather} 
            
    \textbf{Example 1:} Evaluating a Trigonometric Function \newline
    
        A. Find the exact value of $\displaystyle \sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{12}\right)$

        \begin{align}
            \frac{\pi}{12} &= \frac{4\pi}{12} - \frac{3\pi}{2}\\
            &= ~ \frac{\pi}{3} ~~~~~~~\frac{\pi}{4}
        \end{align}

        \begin{align}
            &\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{12}\right) = \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3} - \frac{\pi}{4}\right)\\
            &= \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) - \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\\
            &= \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\\
            &= \frac{\sqrt{6}}{4} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} = \frac{\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2}}{4}
        \end{align}
        
        B. Find the exact value of $\cos(\ang{75}).$   

        \begin{align}
            &\cos(\overset{\alpha}{\ang{30}} + \overset{\beta}{\ang{45}})\\
            &= \cos(\ang{30})\cos(\ang{45})-\sin(\ang{30})\sin(\ang{45})\\
            &= \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) - \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\\
            &= \frac{\sqrt{6}}{4} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} = \frac{\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2}}{4}
        \end{align}
        
    \textbf{Example 2}: Proving a Cofunction Identity \newline

        Use a difference formula to prove the cofunction identity:

        \begin{gather}   
        \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right) = \sin(x) 
        \end{gather}

        \begin{align}
            \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right) &= \cos \overset{0}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)} \cos(x) + \sin \overset{1}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)} \sin(x)\\
            &= 0 \ast \cos(x) + 1 \ast \sin(x)\\
            &= \sin(x)
        \end{align}
        
    \textbf{Example 3:} Solve
    
        \[
        \sin\overset{\alpha}{(x)}\sin\overset{\beta}{(2x)} + \cos\overset{\alpha}{(x)}\cos\overset{\beta}{(2x)} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} 
        \]

                Recall: $\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$    

        \begin{align}
            \cos (x - 2x) &= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
            &\cos (-x) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
            &\cos x = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
            &x = \frac{\pi}{6} + 2 \pi k\\
            &x = \frac{11 \pi}{6} + 2 \pi k
        \end{align}
        
            Identities \newline

            The Product to Sum Identities

            \begin{gather}
                \sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) = \frac{1}{2}(\sin(\alpha + \beta) + \sin(\alpha - \beta))\\
                \sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(\alpha - \beta) + \cos(\alpha + \beta))\\
                \cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(\alpha + \beta) + \cos(\alpha - \beta))
            \end{gather}
            
    \textbf{Example 4:} Write $\sin\overset{\alpha}{(2t)}\sin\overset{\beta}{(4t)}$ as a sum or difference

            \begin{align}
                &= \frac{1}{2}(\cos(2t - 4t) - \cos(2t + 4t))\\
                &= \frac{1}{2}(\cos(-2t) - \cos (6t))\\
                &= \frac{1}{2} (\cos(2t) - \cos (6t))
            \end{align}
            
            Identities \newline

            The Sum to Product Identities

            \begin{align}
                \sin(u) + \sin(v) = 2\sin\left(\frac{u + v}{2}\right)\cos
                \left(\frac{u - v}{2}\right)\\
                \sin(u) - \sin(v) = 2\sin\left(\frac{u - v}{2}\right)\cos
                \left(\frac{u + v}{2}\right)\\
                \cos(u) + \cos(v) = 2\cos\left(\frac{u + v}{2}\right)\cos
                \left(\frac{u - v}{2}\right)\\
                \cos(u) - \cos(v) = 2\cos\left(\frac{u - v}{2}\right)\cos
                \left(\frac{u + v}{2}\right)
            \end{align}
            
    \textbf{Example 5:} Evaluate $\cos\stackon{(\ang{15})}{u} - \cos\stackon{(\ang{75})}{v}$ \newline

    Recall: $\sin(-30) = -\sin(30)$

            \begin{align}
                &-2 \sin \left(\frac{\ang{15} + \ang{75}}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\ang{15} - \ang{75}}{2}\right)\\
                &+ 2 \sin (\ang{45}) ~ \sin (\ang{30})\\
                &= \cancel{2} \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\cancel{2}}\right) \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)
            \end{align}


\end{document}
```

[image]

If anyone could help with this, it would be a huge help

Comment: Can you include images of your code's output to show what you mean by "squish"? It'd help us spot the issue. I compiled your code both with and without the math, and I didn't see much of a difference between the two.

Comment: `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 70--71`  never end a paragraph with `\newline`  or `\\ ` !!!!  also never leave a blank line in the source before a display environment such as `align`

Comment: I added an image of your two documents, it all looks as expected although the white space is bad in the example with math  as latex warns, but that does not affect the title. Please clarify your question.

Comment: You could try `\raggedbottom` or put `\maketitle` inside a minipage.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle what do I use instead then? \vspace{.5cm}?

Comment: You should not need any markup at all. An end of paragraph is marked by a blank line in the source, how that formats is set globally by the document class you should never be adding space on every instance (and `\newline` does not add space it adds an extra blank line of text which is not dropped at a page break and will break all latex's control over bad line breaks at the ends of paragraphs)

Comment: @JohnKormylo may you please show me code with those methods used in the 2nd code example? I am unfamiliar with those commands

Comment: @bonk images are added now

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so identities and the sum and difference identities shouldnt have a space between them? Should I utilize section and subsections? How would you do this code differently?

Comment: never have blank lines or adjacent math displays, and  use real alignement not `~ \frac{\pi}{3} ~~~~~~~\frac` (also isn't a `-` missing on that line?) , your non-alignment between eqn 7 and 8 also looks a bit odd why is the = not aligned?